# Get id of of submit type?Is it possible?

Tags: php, html, submit

Is it possible to get the value of submit button's id? I can't use Javascript because I wamt to insert values to MySql. Following is my code.

```
<form action="messages.php"  method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="accept" value="accept" id='.$id.'/>
    </form>



if (isset($_POST['accept']))
    {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;   
    }
```

Comment: Send it using a `hidden` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the value to a hidden input on your form:

```
<i><form action="messages.php"  method="post">
<input type="submit" name="accept" value="accept" id='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
<input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $id; ?>' name="submit_id" />
</form></i>
```

Then you can retrieve it from `$_POST['submit_id']`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it using PHP but you can set its value in a hidden field.

```
<i><form action="messages.php"  method="post">
<input type="submit" name="accept" value="accept" id='.$id.'/>
<input type="hidden" name="acceptID" value="accept" id='.$id.'/>  
</form></i>
```

and get it like:

```
if (isset($_POST['acceptID'])) { $id = $_POST['acceptID']; echo $id;
}
```